# conditional copy in xslt fails

Tags: xslt, altova, map-force

I am trying to write a simple XSLT template that does the following:

1. If input node is present: simply copy the content of input to output
2. If input node is not present: pass a default value to output

My template is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="conditionalCopy">
        <xsl:with-param name="key"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="conditionalCopy">
    <xsl:param name="key"/>
        <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="key">
             <xsl:value-of select="key"/>
           </xsl:when>
           <xsl:otherwise>
             <xsl:text> no value </xsl:text>
           </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But, it always goes into the else case. Btw, I am using it with Altova Mapforce (if that changes anything.)

Please help me to handle this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To access variables or parameters you should use a `$` symbol:

```
<xsl:when test="$key">
    <xsl:value-of select="$key"/>
</xsl:when>
```

Comment: and the `<xsl:with-param name="key"/>` call is empty and could be either `<xsl:with-param name="key" select="value"/>` or `<xsl:with-param name="key">value</xsl:with-param>`